# How can I retrieve dataplex data profile results to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

I have been exploring google cloud dataplex data profiling feature [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/data-profiling-overview)

I followed the steps given in creating the data profile scans and noticed the profile results are shown in the Profile section as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/use-data-profiling#create-scan)

If I want to retrieve those profile results to BigQuery, what options does gcp provides. I did check some of the apis, but did not notice any details to export profile scans to bigquery.

I am fairly new to using google cloud, therefore I may be missing something.

Comment: It's not possible, for now, to export Profiling data to BigQuery automatically. If you want that, you have to write a piece of code (Cloud Run/Cloud Functions for instance) that request the API and sink the data in BigQUery.

Comment: thanks, but can you help me why would google do this? generally, the consumer of such information are generally data governance personas, why wouldn't google enable direct load to BQ when they already do with the other feature auto dq  results

Comment: I'm sure it's in the roadmap (don't have the detail right now)!

Comment: curious to know if the roadmap available for viewing for everyone?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting dataplex data profile results to BigQuery is supported now.

Please check the [public doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/use-data-profiling#create-scan) at Step **Optional: Export the scan results to a BigQuery standard table** for more details.

You can either bring your own table (which schema needs to be compatible with the required [schema](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/use-data-profiling#table-schema)) or let the dataplex created the table for you if the table doesn't exist.

Please make sure the export BigQuery dataset exists and assign the dataplex service account corresponding [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/use-data-profiling#permissions).

Comment: disclaim affiliation? who is "we"?